# onPasswordSucceeded not working

Tags: java, android

I'm using device admin receiver for my android project and I need to execute some code when the correct password is entered and the phone is unlocked. But this onPasswordSucceeded does not seem to be working. Following is my code:

```
public class AdminRec extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
static int failed_attempts = 0;
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //super.onEnabled(context, intent);




}


@Override
public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent) {
    failed_attempts ++;
    Log.i("Failed Attempts",Integer.toString(failed_attempts));

    if(failed_attempts > 2)
    {
        Intent i1 = new Intent(context,MainService.class);
        context.stopService(i1);

        Intent i2 = new Intent(context,MasterPinService.class);
        context.startService(i2);

    }
}

@Override
public void onPasswordSucceeded(Context context, Intent intent) {
    failed_attempts = 0;
    Log.i("Failed Attempts",Integer.toString(failed_attempts));

    Intent i1 = new Intent(context,MainService.class);
    context.startService(i1);

}




}
```

The code inside onPasswordFailed works fine but I need to set the value of int failed_attempts to zero in onPasswordSucceeded which is not happening.

Please guide me where I'm wrong.

Comment: What does your policy xml look like?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
        <disable-camera />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>`